# The deployment cannot use the VirtualNetwork Cryosite_VN_TST_02 that belongs to a region

Tags: windows, azure, deployment, tfs

I am deploying into Azure using the TFS Build. The build fails prompting me an error message with "The deployment cannot use the VirtualNetwork that belongs to a region."

Checked all the setting with the Virtual Network, gateway & local network.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have created your virtual network as a Regional Virtual Network.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/regional-virtual-networks/

I would assume from the error message that Regional Virtual Networks are no supported for the type of deployment you are doing.

Comment: I have tried creating virtual network using region (location) and also by creating affinitygroup. I have referred the link you have provided.

It seems something wrong with the TFS build not sure what it is.

Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Have you tried creating a virtual network using neither of these? Just go to manage.windowsazure.com and create a simple Virtual Network.